# Boostrap Form validation success message not coming

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm working with bootstrap form validation the problem is success message is not coming after form submit I have a PHP mail function script on submitting I'm getting php message echo 'thank you' in a new page even I written `return false` and i was working on local WAMP server. My question is how to get success msg in the same page HTML success msg div. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
      // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
      feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
      },
      fields: {
        first_name: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 2,
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your first name'
            }
          }
        },
        last_name: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 2,
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your last name'
            }
          }
        },
        email: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your email address'
            },
            emailAddress: {
              message: 'Please supply a valid email address'
            }
          }
        },
        phone: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your phone number'
            },
            phone: {
              country: 'US',
              message: 'Please supply a vaild phone number with area code'
            }
          }
        },
        address: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 8,
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your street address'
            }
          }
        },
        city: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 4,
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your city'
            }
          }
        },
        state: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please select your state'
            }
          }
        },
        zip: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your zip code'
            },
            zipCode: {
              country: 'US',
              message: 'Please supply a vaild zip code'
            }
          }
        },
        comment: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 10,
              max: 200,
              message: 'Please enter at least 10 characters and no more than 200'
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply a description of your project'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
      $('#success_message').slideDown({
        opacity: "show"
      }, "slow") // Do something ...
      $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

      // Prevent form submission
      e.preventDefault();

      // Get the form instance
      var $form = $(e.target);

      // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
      var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

      // Use Ajax to submit form data
      $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      }, 'json');
    });
});
```

```css
.form-control {
  padding: 0;
}

#success_message {
  display: none;
}

.has-error .help-block {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js"></script>

<form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post" id="contact_form">

  <!-- Text input-->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
        <input name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Text input-->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
        <input name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Text input-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
        <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Text input-->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Phone #</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
        <input name="phone" placeholder="(845)555-1212" class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Text input-->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Address</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
        <input name="address" placeholder="Address" class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Text input-->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">City</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
        <input name="city" placeholder="city" class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Select Basic -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">State</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
        <select name="state" class="form-control selectpicker">
          <option value=" ">Please select your state</option>
          <option>Alabama</option>
          <option>Alaska</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Text input-->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Zip Code</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
        <input name="zip" placeholder="Zip Code" class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Text input-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Website or domain name</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i></span>
        <input name="website" placeholder="Website or domain name" class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- radio checks -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Do you have hosting?</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="hosting" value="yes" /> Yes
                                </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="hosting" value="no" /> No
                                </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Text area -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Project Description</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Project Description"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Success message -->
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.</div>

  <!-- Button -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to redirect back to contact_form using `header("Location: contact_form.php");`
ie;

```
if( mail( $mail_to, $subject, $msg, $headers )) {
        header("Location: contact_form.php?send=success");
} else {
        die("Error!");
}
```

Note the query string parameter `send=success`

Now, in your contact_form.php, before `<form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post" id="contact_form">` add following condition.

```
    <?php
    $send_status = $_GET['send'];
    if(isset($send_status)){
    ?>
       <style>
          #success_message {
            display: block;
          }
      </style>
    <?
    }
    ?>
```

Try this and let us know.

Comment: not working these php code where i have to place /assets/js/contact.js ,  contact-form.php root folder this my directory structure

Comment: I got it. actually, we need to call submitHandler inside bootstrapValidator(); thanks for your help.